# How to passively monitor if a new TCP connection is being made in Linux?

Tags: android, linux, tcp, callback, connection

The easiest way is probably to write a loop to monitor /proc/net/tcp or /proc/net/tcp6. However, it is too inefficient since I need to be notified almost immediately. The closest thing I looked at is inotify which can provide callbacks on IO events on any files. The problem is that procfs is not regular file systems and inotify does not appear to support it (at least not for /proc/net/tcp and /proc/net/tcp6).

Further, I do not want the program to have root privilege in order to implement this.

EDIT: I removed the requirement of userspace connection. Also, I'm hoping that there's a built-in kernel support such as inotify that can achieve this. It may even be too intrusive in my case to manipulate the iptables.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you elaborate on an example situation when a TCP session would be initiated by the linux kernel (and not from user space)?

Comment: Sorry, I figured that the userspace connection is not critical. I removed that in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a logging rule to your local `iptables` configuration that would log a message whenever a new connection is initiated, and then make the log file readable by a non-root user.  This would get you (a) immediate notification of events (you could use inotify to detect writes to the file) and (b) the detecting process itself does not need root privileges.

Comment: How does an `iptables` solution alone account for TCP sessions initiated in user-space (as opposed to those initiated by the kernel)?

Comment: I guess it doesn't, particularly, although the number of kernel-initiated tcp connections is going to be (a) relatively small in number and (b) relatively static in terms of ports, so in theory easy to filter out.  In fact, as I think about it I'm not able to come up with an example of a kernel-initiated TCP connection.  I think even something like NFS-over-TCP is initiated in user-space.  Can you help me out with an example?

Comment: I guess my contention is, absent a contrary example, that all TCP connections are initiated in user space on a typical system.

Comment: Changing iptables may still be too intrusive. For instance, what if I want to develop an application on unrooted android phones where I cannot change the iptables? I'm not very familiar with ptrace. Can an unprivileged app use ptrace to monitor system calls of other apps?

Comment: Nope, pretty much the only things you can detect about other apps are what is [readable and reads non-empty for a foreign process] in /proc, and inotify on actual files.

Comment: You can use ptrace to detect calls such as connect(2) and work with that. However, you can only attach to one process at a time, performance would be horrible if you attached to all processes. A different solution which would do pretty much the same thing as ptrace is to LD_PRELOAD something which looks into `connect()`. On that note, you can use ptrace to monkey patch each binary as it loads (this would require knowledge of the PLT, and probably some assembler).. in other words, it's a mess

Answer (score 1):

Best thing I can think of is trying to run an on-board proxy and persuade other apps to connect through that.  Some have tried to do this by altering the APN settings.

But this is ugly, may not work on all versions, and can probably be circumvented.

Unfortunately, Android just isn't designed to allow end users to install optional improvements to the behavior of the system itself, short of cracking the whole thing open (ie, rooting).

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible to monitor outbound traffic using raw sockets. See man page for packet (7) to see how to do that. However, this may not be what you want.

If connection-tracking is enabled, it may be possible to get notifications of new connections from the kernel using netlink. The API for doing these things is awful, so consider looking at the source of a program which does it already. I think the "conntrack" binary may be supplied with some distributions (I'm not sure what it's part of).

Comment: can you do this without special priveleges?  Seems like a solution which works on secured consumer-destined android devices is desired.  Ie, linux, but without a way for the device owner to do/permit what would be administrative tasks on a traditional system.